# Why was everything mirrored at the end of Veronica?

Tags: plot-explanation, veronica

I recently watched [*Veronica*](https://www.netflix.com/ca/title/80109295) on Netflix, and noticed that at the end of the movie, after Veronica hits her head on the bathroom mirror, everything becomes mirror-inverted. For example, the door to Veronica‘s room opens the other way, the posters in her room are inverted, etc.

I couldn’t really figure out the significance of this for the movie, or the exact reason why this is happening. Does anybody haver any idea why that is happening?